# Apache write permission in public_html?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, centos, permissions

I have an account on a hosted webserver, where I have SSH access.

Files put in `/home/sandra/public_html` are online.

DokuWiki recommends that the `data` and `conf` directory is not in `Document Root`, so I have moved them to `/home/sandra/data/` and `/home/sandra/conf`.

The problem is, that `apache` can't write to these directories.

Ownership of `/home/sandra/` is `sandra.sandra`.

**Question**

Are there other solutions to this problem than

```
chmod 777 /home/sandra
```

Can the root user help me out?

Comment: Hello Sandra, Changing the ownership of the directory you want your web server to write to the users who is running web server will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *Hex* already wrote, the directory must be writable for the user under which Apache runs. You can achieve this by changing the group to the Apache user's primary group (www-data on Ubuntu) and give the group write permission.

```
chgrp -R www-data /home/sandra/data /home/sandra/conf
chmod -R g+rwX /home/sandra/data /home/sandra/conf
```

The user must also be able to `cd` into those directories, so it needs `execute` permissions on the parent directory.

```
chmod o+X /home/sandra
```

Another option would be to add respective ACLs for the Apache user, if the filesystem supports them.

```
setfacl -m default:u:www-data:rwx /home/sandra/data /home/sandra/conf
setfacl -m u:www-data:x /home/sandra
```

I wouldn't recommend changing the owner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
chown -R apache /home/sandra/conf
```

This command will make apache the owner of these files. You can then give apache full access to the folderby doing

```
chmod 770 /home/sandra/conf
```

Both commands must be run on both folders respectively.